# ASP.NET 5 Multiple Projects one solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, yeoman, dnvm

I have recently started trying out ASP.NET 5, specifically starting a project with [yo-aspnet generator](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/yeoman.html).

I am trying to figure out how to create a solution with multiple projects, like was normal in the pre-ASP.NET 5 days. For example, a solution with a WebApp project, WebApi project, and a unit test project for each.

There does not seem to be a yeoman generator to make a solution structure like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to structure it yourself if you're just doing it in the command line and not a visual studio solution. So what you would do is have something like:

```
MyCoolApp /
--.gitignore
--README.md
--/src
  --MyCoolApp.WebApp
  --MyCoolApp.WebApi
  --MyCoolApp.Domain
--/test
  --MyCoolApp.Domain.Tests
```

Which you'll achieve by creating the `MyCoolApp` folder. `cd` into it. Do your `git init` and add a `.gitignore` from Github. Then make your `src` and `test` directories. `cd` into `src`. `yo generator-aspnet` pick WebApplication and name it MyCoolApp.WebApp. Wash/Rinse/Repeat.

Then in the `project.json` file add the dependencies to the other projects. You'll probably also want to clean up the duplicate `.gitignore` files.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was wondering what the current best practices way of doing this was with yeoman.